# Python ARIMA: no trend(i.e., constant) when d is not zero

Tags: statsmodels, arima

Based on the equation for ARIMA model, it includes a constant.

[image]

But the ARIMA implementation in python statsmodels library assume no trend (i.e., no constant) when d is not zero. See specifications [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html). Why is that?